# opening cmd and scripts from GUI tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i have a few files. A gui and some few scripts. How am i able to get the gui to open up cmd so that i can get variable(the text) from my gui and pass it to the cmd with the script i selected?

For example,

i got the appended string from variables i got from my GUI ( gui.py) `Tonight.mp3 16 00:00:00 00:00:00 G` and then selected the desired script (segmentation.py)

finally, i need to pass it to cmd

which is

```
segmentation.py Tonight.mp3 16 00:00:00 00:00:00
```

What is your advice? i know i have to use subprocess or os

example:

```
def printing():
    commandline = " " + a + " " + str(chunk.get()) + " " + str(start_censorship.get()) + " " + str(end_censorship.get())
    print commandline
    import subprocess
    subprocess.call(["C:\Users\Xavier_\Desktop\PROJECT\segmentation.py"])
##    cmd = subprocess.Popen(["C:\Users\Xavier_\Desktop\PROJECT\segmentation.py" , str(a), str(chunk.get()), str(start_censorship.get()), str(end_censorship.get())], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
##    output = cmd.communicate()   
segmentButton = Button( root,text='Segment', fg="Red",command=printing)
segmentButton.pack(side=Tkinter.TOP)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [communicate method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) to get the output. For example:

```
import subprocess
cmd = subprocess.Popen(["segmentation.py", str(a), str(chunk.get()), str(start_censorship.get()), str(start_censorship.get())], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = cmd.communicate()
```

The output form the command is returned from `communicate()` when stdout is set to subprocess.PIPE.

Comment: i don't get any cmd prompt? is there anything wrong?

Comment: It doesn't open a "command prompt" that you can see. It runs the command in the background, and stores the command output in the `output` variable.

Comment: i am trying to run a script with command line so if nothing happened, that means there is error?

Comment: No, it means that it ran the script fine, and that the output is in the `output` variable. Try running `print output` afterwards to see it.

Comment: i did tried printing the output,and it gave me this "('', None)"

Comment: What does your other script do?

Comment: i have a few python file in a folder so what i am doing is to run your example on one of my file which is in a gui. i have to pass the variable to a cmd line, so that i can run a script that is being placed in the same folder for gui

Comment: the other file does segmenting and when i try to run the script in cmd,it works (in standalone)

Comment: Oh, your other python file opens up a GUI window?

Comment: no i am implementing your example on my GUI, i have a button which is "segment" which will print the variable(to double check),to be passed on a cmd and at the same time,to get a filename called segmentation.py. which the cmd line will show segmentation.py Tonight.mp3 16 00:00:00 00:00:00 and run the script

Comment: What does segmentation.py output?

Comment: it will have a lot of segmented files in the same folder

Comment: I mean when you run it, does it print anything out to the console?

Comment: Well, the communicate() method returns what it prints to the console, so if it prints nothing to the console then it has no output. What do you want to retrieve from the script?